# Get NEXT Sunday date based on the given date (in [yyyy][mm][dd]) format

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

[image: Date format i'm trying to manipulate]

In cell C3 the date format is [yyyy][mm][dd], what i would like to do in a single cell is get the date from that cell (which i just take with LEFT, MID and RIGHT functions) and add until sunday ([dd].[mm].[yyyy] format) in the same cell.

On the example i gave, the date is 07.06.2022, so the part i'm missing with function is "**- 12.06.2022**".

The formula in C2 cell is this: `=RIGHT(C3;2)&"."&MID(C3;5;2)&"."&LEFT(C3;4)&" - 12.06.2022"`

What i also tried to do is get the real DATE (with function), like this: `=DATE(LEFT(C3;4);MID(C3;5;2);RIGHT(C3;2))`

But with that function, this would require me to select the cell as "DATE" format and then i'm not sure how to have a whole string (07.06.2022 - 12.06.2022) in that cell, because as soon as i add **&" - "** to the formula, the cell will not display the date anymore, only numbers (that cell is in "Date" format:

[image: Adding anything to Date cell]

Is there any way to do what i'm trying to do? Bonus would also be, to get Monday to Sunday date (06.06.2022 - 12.06.2022) from the selected date, but i would be happy with getting Sunday " - 12.06.2022" with a function only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ***Excel 365*** can try-

```
=LET(x,DATE(LEFT(A1,4),MID(A1,5,2),RIGHT(A1,2)),FILTER(SEQUENCE(7,,x,1),WEEKDAY(SEQUENCE(7,,x,1),1)=1))
```

[image]

Comment: I can work with that, taking your formula and added everything else, i can get this from a single cell formula:

`=RIGHT(A1;2)&"."&MID(A1;5;2)&"."&LEFT(A1;4)&" - "&TEXT(LET(x;DATE(LEFT(A1;4);MID(A1;5;2);RIGHT(A1;2));FILTER(SEQUENCE(7;;x;1);WEEKDAY(SEQUENCE(7;;x;1);1)=1));"dd.mm.yyyy")`

This is what the final Formula would look like and actually works. The end result is: **07.06.2022 - 12.06.2022**

Comment: Btw, what would need to be changed from your formula, to get "Monday" out of it? Basically **06.06.2022** date.

Comment: Then change 1 to 2 in Filter formula comparison. It would be `=2` instead of `=1` in filter formula.

Answer (score 1):

After playing around a bit with the help of @Harun24hr's formula to get Sunday, this is the final result which i'm happy with:

```
=LET(Date;DATE(LEFT(A1;4);MID(A1;5;2);RIGHT(A1;2));TEXT(Date-WEEKDAY(Date;2)+1;"dd.mm.yyyy")&" - "&TEXT(FILTER(SEQUENCE(7;;Date;1);WEEKDAY(SEQUENCE(7;;Date;1);1)=1);"dd.mm.yyyy"))
```

This would get "Monday - Sunday" date.

Taking "**20220611**" as example, the above function would return: **06.06.2022 - 12.06.2022**